# Помогите оформить вывод таблицы Delphi

Tags: delphi

```
program lab2v2;
// Данная программа сравнивает шейкерную сортировку и
// сортировку бинарными вставками по количеству
// присваиваний

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

type
  TArray = array [1 .. 3000] of integer;
  TDateArray = array [1 .. 6] of integer;

  { TBaseOfArray - базовый типа массива
    TArray - тип-массив }

const
  ArrLength: TDateArray = (100, 250, 500, 1000, 2000, 3000);

  { ArrLength - массив, хранящий длины массивов }


  // Процедура, меняющая местами элементы массива Element1
  // и Element2

  { Element1, Element2 - две элемента массива, меняющиеся местами }

procedure Swap(var Element1, Element2: integer);
var
  Temp: integer;

  { Temp - переменная для хранения одного из элементов при замене }

begin
  Temp := Element1;
  Element1 := Element2;
  Element2 := Temp;
end;


// Шейкерная сортировка

{ NumberOfSwaps - число перестановок
  Arr - сортируемый массив }

function CoctailSort(var Arr: TArray; var kol: integer): integer;
var
  i, Left, Right, NumberOfSwaps: integer;

  { i - счётчик цикла
    Left, Right - левая и правая границы в шейкерной
    сортировке
    LastSwap - место последнего обмена для более быстрого
    сужения границ }

begin
  NumberOfSwaps := 0;
  Left := 1;
  Right := kol;
  while Left < Right do
  begin
    // Проход слева направо
    for i := Left to Right - 1 do
      if Arr[i] > Arr[i + 1] then
      begin
        Swap(Arr[i], Arr[i + 1]);
        Inc(NumberOfSwaps, 1);
      end;

    // Проход справа налево
    for i := Right downto Left + 1 do
      if Arr[i] < Arr[i - 1] then
      begin
        Swap(Arr[i], Arr[i - 1]);
        Inc(NumberOfSwaps, 1);
      end;

    // Сдвиг левой границы вправо
    Left := Left + 1;
    Right := Right - 1;
  end;
  CoctailSort := NumberOfSwaps;
end;

// Сортировка бинарными вставками

{ NumberOfSwaps - число перестановок
  Arr - сортируемый массив }

function BinaryInsertSort(var Arr: TArray; var kol: integer): integer;
var
  i, j, Left, Right, Middle, NumberOfSwaps, Temp: integer;

  { i, j - счётчики циклов
    Left, Right - левая и правая границы в сортировке
    бинарными вставками
    Middle - середина рассматриваемого отрезка массива в
    сортировке
    Temp - переменнаяя для хранения вставляемого элемента }

begin
  NumberOfSwaps := 0;
  for i := 2 to kol do
  begin
    Left := 1;
    Right := i - 1;
    Temp := Arr[i];

    // Поиск позиции для вставляемого элемента методом
    // бинарного поиска
    repeat

      Middle := (Left + Right) div 2;
      if Arr[Middle] < Temp then
        Left := Middle + 1
      else
        Right := Middle - 1;
    until Left > Right;

    // Сдвиг элементов вправо
    for j := i - 1 downto Left do
    begin
      Arr[j + 1] := Arr[j];
      Inc(NumberOfSwaps);
    end;

    // Вставляем элемент
    Arr[Left] := Temp;
    Inc(NumberOfSwaps, 2);
  end;
  BinaryInsertSort := NumberOfSwaps;
end;


// Заполнение массива Arr случайными значениями

{ Arr - заполняемый массив
  MaxNumber - максимальный возможный элемент массива }

procedure RandomFill(var Arr: TArray; kol: integer);
var
  i: integer;

  { i - счётчик цикла }

begin
  Randomize;
  for i := 1 to kol do
    // Элемент массива инициализируется случайным
    // натуральным числом не больше MaxNumber
    Arr[i] := Random(kol) + 1;
end;


// Переворачивание массива

{ Arr - переворачиваемый массив }

procedure Reverse(var Arr: TArray; kol: integer);
var
  i: integer;

  { i - счётчик цикла }

begin
  for i := 1 to kol div 2 do
    Swap(Arr[i], Arr[kol - i + 1]);
end;


// Основной алгоритм

var
  i, j, k, m, Swaps, N, res: integer;
  Arr: TArray;
  MaxElement: integer;
  CoctailSwaps: array [1 .. 3, 1 .. 6] of integer;
  InsertSwaps: array [1 .. 3, 1 .. 6] of integer;
  ErrorString: String;
  ErrorCode: integer;
  ErrorFlag: Boolean;

  { i, j - счётчики цикла
    Swaps - количество перестановок
    Arr - сортируемый массив
    CoctailSwaps - массив, хранящий количество
    перестановок в шейкерной сортировке для массивов
    разных размеров
    InsertSwaps - массив, хранящий количество перестановок
    в сортировке бинарными вставками для массивов разных
    размеров }

begin
  // Заполнение массивов, хранящих перестановки, нулями
  // FillChar заполняет 3 * SizeOf(TDateArray) байт в
  // CoctailSwaps значениями 0
  FillChar(CoctailSwaps, 3 * SizeOf(TDateArray), 0);
  FillChar(InsertSwaps, 3 * SizeOf(TDateArray), 0);

  for i := 1 to 6 do
  begin
    N := ArrLength[i];

    // Измеряем количество перестановок 3 раза и находим среднее
    for j := 1 to 2 do
    begin
      (* Шейкерная сортировка *)

      // Сортировка случайного массива

      RandomFill(Arr, N);
      res := CoctailSort(Arr, N);
      Inc(CoctailSwaps[1][i], res);

      (* Бинарные вставки *)

      // Сортировка случайного массива
      RandomFill(Arr, N);
      res := BinaryInsertSort(Arr, N);
      Inc(InsertSwaps[1][i], res);
    end;

    (* Шейкерная сортировка *)

    // Сортировка случайного массива

    RandomFill(Arr, N);
    res := CoctailSort(Arr, N);
    Inc(CoctailSwaps[1][i], res);

    // Сортировка отсортированного массива
    res := CoctailSort(Arr, N);
    CoctailSwaps[2][i] := res;

    // Сортировка перевернутого массива

    Reverse(Arr, N);
    res := CoctailSort(Arr, N);
    CoctailSwaps[3][i] := res;

    (* Бинарные вставки *)

    // Сортировка случайного массива
    RandomFill(Arr, N);
    res := BinaryInsertSort(Arr, N);
    Inc(InsertSwaps[1][i], res);

    // Сортировка отсортированного массива
    res := BinaryInsertSort(Arr, N);
    InsertSwaps[2][i] := res;
    // Сортировка перевернутого массива
    Reverse(Arr, N);
    res := BinaryInsertSort(Arr, N);
    InsertSwaps[3][i] := res;

    CoctailSwaps[1][i] := CoctailSwaps[1][i] div 3;
    InsertSwaps[1][i] := InsertSwaps[1][i] div 3;
  end;

  // Вывод результатов

  for i := 1 to 36 do
    Write('_');
  WriteLn;
  Write('|  array  | array |cocktail| binary|');
  WriteLn;
  Write('|dimension|  type | sorting| insert|');
  WriteLn;
  Write('|         |       |        |sorting|');
  WriteLn;
  Write('|_________|_______|________|_______|');
  WriteLn;
  for k := 1 to 6 do
  begin
    Write('|N = ', ArrLength[k]);

      Write('  |random| ', CoctailSwaps[1][k]:7, '|', InsertSwaps[1][k]:7, '|');
      WriteLn;
      Write('|         |_______|________|_______|');
      WriteLn;

      Write('|         | sorted|', CoctailSwaps[2][k]:7, '|',
        InsertSwaps[2][k]:8, '|');
      WriteLn;
      Write('|         |_______|________|_______|');
      WriteLn;

      Write('|         |reverse|', CoctailSwaps[3][k]:7, '|',
        InsertSwaps[3][k]:8, '|');
      WriteLn;
      Write('|_________|_______|________|_______|');
      WriteLn;


  end;


  ReadLn;

end.
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Никак не могу оформить вывод таблицы, помогите разобраться с табуляцией. Все время съезжают границы в некоторых частях таблицы(см. рисунок)

Comment: дополни вопрос скриншотом таблицы и что именно съезжает

Comment: Благодарю, исправлено

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 for i := 1 to 39 do
    Write('_');
  WriteLn;
  Writeln('|  array   | array  |cocktail | binary |');
  Writeln('|dimension |  type  | sorting | insert |');
  Writeln('|          |        |         |sorting |');
  Writeln('|__________|________|_________|________|');
  for k := 1 to 6 do
  begin
      Writeln('|N = ', ArrLength[k]:4,'  | random | ', CoctailSwaps[1][k]:8, '|', InsertSwaps[1][k]:8, '|');
      Writeln('|          |________|_________|________|');

      Writeln('|          | sorted | ', CoctailSwaps[2][k]:8, '|', InsertSwaps[2][k]:8, '|');
      Writeln('|          |________|_________|________|');

      Writeln('|          | reverse| ', CoctailSwaps[3][k]:8, '|',  InsertSwaps[3][k]:8, '|');
      Writeln('|__________|________|_________|________|');
  end;
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за решение